# MySQL in XAMPP not allowing remote connections

Tags: php, mysql

After following some online tutorials, allowing wildcard (%) connections to the user, assuring that the port and firewall allow connections, and comparing the login info, I'm at a complete loss recving MySQL error 111.

The script I'm using to connect [PHP]

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('remotehost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db');
```

I believe everything is in order, isn't it?

What should my next step be?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be here asking for help if I hadn't googled it. I wouldn't have followed all the tutorials I had. Please provide some real help and stop wasting your time and mine.

Comment: Does your MySQL database contain a line `skip-networking`? Some databases refuse connections other than the local host...